# Rebuild same docker image with only the additional changes in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

I build an docker image using a Dockerfile. After building the image, I made some basic changes on the Dockerfile. Is it possible to rebuild the same image with just the additional changes. Since, it takes very long time to create the image, I don't want to build it completely. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

All docker build work in the way, that you describe.

The only thing need to be taken into account is layer dependencies.

Consider Dockerfile

```
FROM something
RUN  cmd1
RUN  cmd2
RUN  cmd3
RUN  cmd4
```

If you change `cmd1` then all layers will be rebuilt, because they could be different with respect to `cmd1`
If you change `cmd4` than only this command will be rebuilt, because it has not affect any other layers.

Think about what commands need to be run in what order - maybe you can improve it by reordering the statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you tag your docker image myimage, just start your other Dockerfile with

`FROM myimage`

and put after this your additional changes

Comment: Note that this assumes the edited/tagged image will be available in the future, e.g., saved in an accessible repo. While it may work, it's a pretty brittle solution since it can't be recreated via Dockerfiles or code repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rebuild it with the changes, you would need to store persistent data on a volume for that.

To save your changes,however, you can use `commit`:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

> Create a new image from a container's changes

`docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`

> **It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings into
>   a new image.** This allows you debug a container by running an
>   interactive shell, or to export a working dataset to another server.
>   *Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a
>   documented and maintainable way.* [Read more about valid image names and
>   tags.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/)
>
> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes
>   mounted inside the container.
>
> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be
>   paused while the image is committed. This reduces the likelihood of
>   encountering data corruption during the process of creating the
>   commit.

Comment: Note that while you can do this, it's a bit of an anti-pattern for Docker. Ideally you would want to incorporate any final updates into your Dockerfile (or volume, if needed).

Comment: Yes, but he docker commit will only reflect on container not the image itself.